# How can I display my page to be visible partially on left when the panel scroll left is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

IN this [link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/) , I can find that there is over lay option where I can hide or show the panel on right or left. But I want to display the panel 90% or + in panel. The same example as in facebook mobile where we have option of seeing friends list on right simultaneously a little part of news feed.

I have tried some code in the link provided above which has the code as

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
<!-- panel content goes here -->
</div><!-- /panel -->

 <!-- header -->
  <!-- content -->
  <!-- footer -->

  </div><!-- page -->
```

what more must be implemented for this to bring it to the state when when the panel is visible only 90% of my page must be hidden towards one side of the page.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the plugin use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(17em,0,0);` to move panels. Try to override the 17em value. Also, change it here `.ui-panel-position-left {
left: -17em;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override many class in order to achieve **90%** panel of page.

1. Panel overall width:

   ```
   .ui-panel {
     width: 90%;
   }
   ```
2. Panel's position (left):

   Equals to Panel's width.

   ```
   .ui-panel-position-left {
     left: -90% !important;
   }
   ```
3. Opening panel (3D transform):

   ```
   .ui-panel-open {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(97%, 0, 0) !important;
     transform: translate3d(97%, 0, 0) !important;
   }
   ```
4. Animation:

   Increase or reduce speed (ms).

   ```
   .ui-panel-animate {
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
     transition: transform 500ms ease;
   }
   ```
5. Panel's overlay/wrapper:

   This includes clickable area for panels with `data-dismissible` set to true or false

   ```
   .ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open, .ui-panel-dismiss-position-left.ui-panel-dismiss-open {
     left: 90% !important;
     right: -90% !important;
   }
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jLhvy/)**

Comment: @user3099570 I hope this is what you're looking for :)